# Specific coditional usage

Tags: custom-field, functions, metabox, conditional-content

I have some trouble making work a conditional inside a Function.

check this out:

I'm using this function:

```
function get_spec_1(){
  $desc1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'eco_mb_tp_1', true!= ""  );

  if(!empty ($desc1)){
    foreach ( $desc1 as $d1 ){
      $code = "
      <dl>
      <dt class='bullet6-top'>General</dt>
      <dd>
      <ul>
      <li>$d1</li>
      </ul>
      </dd>
      </dl>
      ";
      echo $code;
    }

  }
}
```

But this function causes this:

```
<dl>
    <dt class='bullet6-top'>Generales</dt>
    <dd>
    <ul>
    <li>$metabox_cloned_value_1</li>
    </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>

<dl>
    <dt class='bullet6-top'>Generales</dt>
    <dd>
    <ul>
    <li>$metabox_cloned_value_2</li>
    </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

But what I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
<dl>
    <dt class='bullet6-top'>Generales</dt>
    <dd>
    <ul>
<li>$metabox_cloned_value_1</li>
<li>$metabox_cloned_value_2</li>
    </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

And if there is no existing data.

then the entire `<dl>` will not show.

How can I obtain this result?

thanks

Comment: You call `get_post_meta()` in a very strange way. What result do you expect? An array of all meta data with this key or just the last value?

Comment: yeah, it is a clone metabox....

Comment: That doesn't answer my question?

Comment: sorry, http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/get-meta-values/ in the section : Get cloned values

Comment: Again (last attempt): Why do you set the last parameter of `get_post_meta()` not to a simple `true` or `false`? What is the expected result?

Comment: o no , sorry was a terrible approach to get_post_meta(), nothing to achieve there... just trying non sense.. hahaha :)

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. Because the DL, DT, DD, and UL are all within the foreach loop, that is why they are being duplicated. Here is the proper code:

```
function get_spec_1(){
  $desc1 = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'eco_mb_tp_1', true );

  if( !empty( $desc1 ) ){
    // Open the stuff
    $code = "
      <dl>
      <dt class='bullet6-top'>General</dt>
      <dd>
      <ul>";
    // Loop through the items once inside the ul
    foreach ( $desc1 as $d1 ){
      code .="<li>$d1</li>";
    }
    // Close the stuff
    code.="
      </ul>
      </dd>
      </dl>
      ";
    echo $code;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer...

but , it does do the trick, put the <li> in the correct place, but the <dl> still there if the content doesn't exist:

live url: http://ecolife.mx/productos/solatube/solar-star/

Comment: It seems that because it is a cloned content , it will not recognise the $desc1 function...

Comment: What is this: `true!= ""`?

Comment: toscho kaiser , 
was a terrible approach to get_post_meta(), nothing to achieve there... just trying non sense.. hahaha :)

Comment: I believe the issue is most likely the if statement. I am fixing it - before you had a space between `!empty` and it's brackets.

Comment: well, nope, Seems that the problem is that the $desc1 is not empty, when I print_r $desc1 , show that have some empty data there, but , don't may be a bug in the metabox function...